# How do I determine if my laptop can charge through USB-C charger? I do have a C type port on my laptop but not sure if it will charge

Tags: laptop, usb-c, charging

I have a HP Laptop PC 15-dw3000 (31R09AV) with a USB-C port.

If I don't have a cable to test it with, is there a way to determine if my computer can charge through this port?

If I do have a USB-C cable that I can connect to a power source and I plug it into my laptop, will simply plugging it in give me a definitive answer, or is it possible that it won't charge through it until I configure it on my computer?

Comment: Why not look in the user's manual? They're online, e.g., at https://www.manualowl.com/p/Hewlett-Packard/PC-15-dw3000/Manual/328807

Answer (score 3):

Simply plugging a USB-C charger into the port will determine if it can charge from the port.  USC-C will auto-negotiate charging capabilities.  If the laptop cannot charge by USB-C, then nothing will happen.  If it is capable of charging by USB-C and the charger does not supply enough power, the operating system should tell you that.  Of course, if it does work, then you will see the battery charging.

All that being said, I dont believe I have seen a laptop that can be charged both by USB-C and another standard charger.  Multiple power inputs means more connectors and electronics, which costs more money. Laptop manufacturers are always trying to avoid raising costs.

Comment: Microsoft Suface devices have dedicated chargers that use the Surface Connect port (a slightly odd magnetic port) and since the Surface Pro 7 are also able to be charged by USB C. You can use either to charge. Just a data point.

Comment: @Mokubai well, there ya go.  Learn something new every day.

Comment: I have a cheap laptop (like Celeron grade) that can be charged from both its "barrel" jack and its USB-C port as well (although the firmware or so seem to be flawed/bugged that it only charges from the latter when the laptop went no further than S3).

Comment: Some generations of thinkpad support charging both by USB C and by the Lenovo "slim tip" charger.

Answer (score 0):

> If I don't have a cable to test it with, is there a way to determine if my computer can charge through this port?

Unfortunately I don't think there is any way to tell visually. You can try searching for the model number to see if you can find a user manual or users reporting experiance.

> If I do have a USB-C cable that I can connect to a power source and I plug it into my laptop, will simply plugging it in give me a definitive answer,

Be aware that most laptops need 20V to charge. So you need a USB C charger that is intended for charging latops, Chargers that are only intended to charge phones are unlikely to work.

> or is it possible that it won't charge through it until I configure it on my computer?

I have never heard of a computer requring configuration to charge.